# How to enter the ingress host as a variable

Tags: kubernetes-helm

helm chart's ingress.yaml is as follows

```
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.server.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
{{ if $extraPaths }}
```

values.yaml로 부터 host입력을 합니다.

```
      hosts:
        - host: vault-{{ .Release.Namespace }}.example.com
          paths:
            - /
```

the expected result..

```
      hosts:
        - host: vault-test-namespace.example.com
          paths:
            - /
```

but result ..

```
      hosts:
        - host: vault-{{ .Release.Namespace }}.example.com
          paths:
            - /
```

How can I get the results I want?

the expected result..

```
      hosts:
        - host: vault-test-namespace.example.com
          paths:
            - /
```